# How does the TVirtualTreeview editor work?

Tags: delphi, virtualtreeview

I am exploring Virtual Treeview in Delphi and ran a sample program where the editor is invoked by pressing F2 beginning the editing process uses the built-in editor in Virtualtreeview (No attached editing component).  The text changed, but immediately changed back to the original when I clicked on a different node.

This led me to explore the source code in VirtualTrees.pas to study how the editing process works. Everything appears to boil down to the `TBaseVirtualTree.doedit`.  I have examined each step but am uncertain what exactly operates the editing box positioned in the column.

```
procedure TBaseVirtualTree.DoEdit;

begin
  Application.CancelHint;
  StopTimer(ScrollTimer);
  StopTimer(EditTimer);
  DoStateChange([], [tsEditPending]);
  if Assigned(FFocusedNode) and not (vsDisabled in FFocusedNode.States) and
    not (toReadOnly in FOptions.FMiscOptions) and (FEditLink = nil) then
  begin
    FEditLink := DoCreateEditor(FFocusedNode, FEditColumn);
    if Assigned(FEditLink) then
    begin
      DoStateChange([tsEditing], [tsDrawSelecting, tsDrawSelPending, tsToggleFocusedSelection, tsOLEDragPending,
        tsOLEDragging, tsClearPending, tsDrawSelPending, tsScrollPending, tsScrolling, tsMouseCheckPending]);
      ScrollIntoView(FFocusedNode, toCenterScrollIntoView in FOptions.SelectionOptions,
        not (toDisableAutoscrollOnEdit in FOptions.AutoOptions));
      if FEditLink.PrepareEdit(Self, FFocusedNode, FEditColumn) then
      begin
        UpdateEditBounds;
        // Node needs repaint because the selection rectangle and static text must disappear.
        InvalidateNode(FFocusedNode);
        if not FEditLink.BeginEdit then
          DoStateChange([], [tsEditing]);
      end
      else
        DoStateChange([], [tsEditing]);
      if not (tsEditing in FStates) then
        FEditLink := nil;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

So my question is how is the actual keyboard input being placed in the node.text by VirtualTree and how is the result of the edit placed into the data record?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to handle the `OnNewText` event eg:

```
procedure TForm1.VSTNewText(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree; Node: PVirtualNode; Column: TColumnIndex; Text: UnicodeString);
var
  data: TMyData;
begin
  data := TMyData(Sender.GetNodeData(Node)^);
  if Assigned(data) then
  begin
    if Column = 0 then
      data.Caption := Text
    else
      data.Value := Text;
  end;
end;
```

This event is called right after you edit the text in the editor.

The editor is implemented via the `IVTEditLink` interface. `FEditLink.BeginEdit` starts the process of the editing.

The build-in editor `TStringEditLink` implements `IVTEditLink`, and if you want to know how that works, You need to study the code.

If you need to use your own editor (eg a ComboBox like editor) you will need to implement `IVTEditLink` and return your `EditLink` in the  `OnCreateEditor` event.

There are a few good examples of property editors in the Demo directory of the VST, that show how to implement your own editors.